# Display input fields based on a variable number in state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the below piece of code. I have defined a `const` in state called items. This is the dropdown selection. It has value 0, 1 and 2 and these indicate no. of dependents.

Once user selects this dropdown, i then update the value of selected dropdown in `dependents` constant using `useState`.

I want to display input field below this which will allow user to enter `dependents` age. For e.g. user selects 2 in dropdown. I want to show 2 input fields below which will allow user to enter the age of 2 `dependents`. Similarly, if i select 1- i should only show 1 input field. In that way it should show dynamically the number of input fields as user selects in dropdown.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve it.

```
function App() {
  const [items] = useState([
    { label: "0", value: "0" },
    { label: "1", value: "1" },
    { label: "2", value: "2" }
  ]);
 
  const [dependents, setDependents] = useState("0");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Select Dependents: 
      <select onChange={e => setDependents(e.currentTarget.value)}>
      {items.map(({ label, value }) => (
       <option key={value} value={value}>
       {label}
       </option>
       ))
      }
    </select>
    </div>
  );
}


"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array based on the selected value and map it to render the input:

```
  <div className="App">
      Select Dependents: 
      <select onChange={e => setDependents(e.currentTarget.value)}>
      {items.map(({ label, value }) => (
       <option key={value} value={value}>
       {label}
       </option>
       ))
      }
    </select>
     {[...Array(+dependents)].map((_,index)=>{

         return <input type="text" key={index}  />
       })
     
      }
    </div>
```

Note :

`[...Array(number)]` creates an array of `undefined` items with length equals to `number`, and  `+number` converts a string to number like `+"4"` gives `4`